# how to deploy nodejs api and vuejs app in one server

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

I have developed node rest api and vuejs web applications, 
Im trying to deploy both project in to one aws server which run ubuntu. 
Both applications have different port, 
domain I try to configure api.example.com for api and example.com for vue app. 
I can run both applications once after running the command in SSH, but I need them to run it forever. 
What I did,

1. Deploy to apps separately
2. Apps can access with ports

I need them access

1. api.example.com
2. example.com

what are the step to do,
Any changes host file.

Comment: You need a reverse proxy like nginx or Amazon ELB.

Comment: I already installed nginx,

Comment: You need to configure it to forward each domain to a different port.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Glad I could help out. It was an interesting experiment to get it figured out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how we are running our VueJS UI and ExpressJS REST API from the same server.

We are managing our services with [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2).

**VueJS  (Dev Environment, You can add the same settings to production)**

In `package.json` add `"start": "HOST='0.0.0.0' PORT=80 npm run dev",`, where 80 is the port VueJS is listening on, to the `"scripts": {..}` array. Then, after installing PM2, (for dev) we can start VueJS with `cd /location/of/vue/root; sudo pm2 start npm run dev --name Vue -- start`. (Make sure that Apache is not running).

Please note that setting the HOST to 0.0.0.0 is important. Do not set it to LocalHost or your Servers IP address or you may run into issues.

**ExpressJS**

In the `/location/of/express/app.js` add this similar to the bottom of the file: 
`app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081)`, where 8081 is the port your REST API should be listening on. I can then start it with `sudo pm2 start /location/of/express/app.js --name Express`

At this point, the VueJS should be available at www.example.com (implied Port 80) and the REST API would be available at www.example.com:8081.

If you want to have api.example.com/ point to the API, you need to make sure that your DNS is pointing the "api" subdomain to the desired port, or you may have to add the port into the URL as above.

Additionally, you can easily follow the logs through PM2 as well with `pm2 logs APPNAME --lines 100`.

Comment: hi, what is the --name?

Comment: I have error running this command: sudo pm2 start npm run dev --name Vue --start | error: unknown option `--start'

Comment: The `start` and `dev` options needs to be defined in the `scripts` array of your `./package.json` file.  `"scripts": { "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js", "start": "HOST='0.0.0.0' PORT=80 npm run dev" }`

Comment: The `--name` options tells PM2 how to reference the Application/Service when you use commands such as `pm2 logs AppName` or look at status' such as `pm2 list` to see a brief overview of all the applications being managed by PM2.

Comment: Which url do you define in your POST request then, to reach the API?

Answer (score 12):

I found another way to deploy vue app and express/nodejs in one server without using PM. This what I did

1. Build your vue code using `npm run build` command. This will create a folder `dist` which should have `index.html` file and `static` folder.
2. Copy `dist` folder into your server code repository. In my case I created a folder `public` and moved the `dist` folder inside `public`.
3. In `app.js` file right before `module.exports=app` line, copy the following lines of code

   `//These 2 lines make sure that vue and express app are coming from the same server. 
         app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname,"../public/dist/static/"))); 
         app.get('/', function(req,res) {
            res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../public/dist/') });
         });`

First line make sure that the `/static` folder is accessible and second line will serve the `index.html` file when you run the node server. Routing between components will be taken care by vue.